# Angular 7 on Heroku

Tags: angular, heroku, heroku-cli

While running my application on heroku, It shows an Application error. Both commands

`heroku logs --tail`

`heroku logs -n 1500`

give this error for me

> Error: Missing required flag:
>
> -a, --app APP  app to run command against
>
> See more help with --help

Answer (score 0):

The command isn't complete as you can see in the error. You need to provide your app-name to run the command against

Try:

```
heroku logs --app=your-app-name --tail
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro. got it.